# CMD Uses GDI32.DLL to render colors. how do i change the color pallet?

Tags: c++, assembly, colors, cmd, gdi

I have found in `GDI32.DLL` that there is some methods that change the `colors` in the console.

Methods

> GDI32.SetBkColor
>
> GDI32.SetTextColor

And there is much more methods to add `color-pallets`.

Is there a way to change the `color-pallet` to use multiple colors and make a `256-RGB` `console`.

I know that there is `console's` that already have a `256 Color VGA` `color-pallet` but i really want to change the way system works.

The `dll-file` `GDI32.DLL` is prety old and is a system core file that don't have much information on the internet about how `cmd` do use it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you nuts? The amount of documentation on `SetBkColor` and `SetTextColor` is insane. And they have *nothing* to do with the console.

Comment: the console actually does use `SetBkColor` and `SetTextColor` without them you can't color the console.

Comment: @CodeAway Odd, I thought for console output you used things like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes but if i change with `cheat-engine` the `conhost.exe / cmd.exe` address `7FF8FF16393F` to `1` you cant set the background. not even `ansi-escape` codes work. `7FF8FF16393F` is inside the `GDI32.DLL.SetBkColor` function.

Comment: Yes, the console uses `SetBkColor` and `SetTextColor` - so does every other Windows program that displays text. My point is that it's irrelevant to your question of how to change the Cmd color palette, since those functions are capable of using 16 million colors. You need to change the code that *calls* them, which is inside `cmd.exe` itself. Good luck with that. Microsoft provides a [console API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) that gives a lot more control, maybe your program can use that.

Comment: The program `cmd.exe` doesn't use any GDI functions at all. It doesn't draw anything directly, it uses the console functions that MachaelPetch linked. It's `conhost` (or `csrss` on older versions of Windows) that does the drawing. If you want to draw text in arbitrary colours you can create your own window and use GDI to draw the text however you want.

Answer (score 0):

To change the colors in the console you can use:

```
system("color 6B");  // 0x00 to 0xFF
```

To change the number of colors, palette or resolution, you probably need to look at something that used to be called 'set graphics mode', don't know if this is still supported now though..

Comment: That only lets you pick from 16 colors for both background and text, and they aren't the prettiest 16 colors either. It's all meant to be backwards compatible with the earliest PC color displays, which were very primitive.

Comment: @MarkRansom - That's right, twice. But I remember playing around (long time ago) with graphics modes, colors and pixels, but probably this is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to change console text attributes is [SetConsoleTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); you should be able to change foreground/background color.

Also, it is not located in GDI32, as far as i know console functions are all located in kernel32.dll (if not all at least most of them). This should clarify about [GDI32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s uses.